# HSQLDB DbBackup dbPath

Tags: hsqldb, database-backups

I'm trying to create a Offline Backup of my HSQLDB (using HSQLDB 2.2.6.jar) as explained in the HSQLDB User Guide: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#N1400A

```
java -cp path/to/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.lib.tar.DbBackup --save  \
tar/path.tar db/base/path
```

But I can't find out where the db/base/path is supposed to point. This is the remark in the User Guide:

```
db/base/path is the file path to the catalog file base name (in same fashion as in server.database.* settings and JDBC URLs with catalog type file:.
```

And that's the Error Message I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File not found:
path\to\hsqldb.jar.properties
at org.hsqldb.lib.tar.DbBackup.write(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.lib.tar.DbBackup.main(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

The paths in the Guide must be replaced with the paths that you use. For example if you want to save the backup to the directory named /backupdir/ and your database files are named mydatabase and they are located in in /dbdir/, then the command is:

```
java -cp hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.lib.tar.DbBackup --save /backupdir/mydatabase.tar /dbdir/mydatabase
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works. 

Just because this was another the next problem I had: You have to shutdown the Database correctly with the SHUTDOWN SQL Statement to generate a backup. The line Modified in the properties File hast to be set to "no" as explained here: http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/apc.html